# detect URL with Predefined Constants and parse_url for define a constant. Is that the best way?

Tags: php, url

The constants created around the url of the visited page and the hostname with HTTP (S) is clean? Is there a shorter way?

```php
// Define Current Full URL (CFURL)
define('CFURL', 
 (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")."://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

// Define URL Scheme & Host
define('URL_HOST', 
 parse_url(CFURL, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . ':' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . parse_url(CFURL, PHP_URL_HOST));

echo '<strong>Define URL Scheme & Host:</strong><br>'.URL_HOST.'<br>';
```

Comment: IMHO constants should NEVER be set by unpredictable function results.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, what means IMHO?

Comment: IMHO = in my humble opinion

Comment: do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Use environment variables instead.